# Returning file name with Left(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - 1) generates error number 5

Tags: excel, vba

I get

> error number 5

in

```
(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Left(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - 1)
```

The purpose of this code is to put in an Excel sheet the name of all the folders and subfolders and files from a path given.

It happens when it runs 33 times to copy the files from the same folder, so it gets to put data till row 60.

```vb
Sub Principal()
    Call GetFiles("C:\Users\DGGC\Desktop\UNIR BOGC\")
End Sub


Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

Dim subfolder As Object
Dim file As Object

For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    GetFiles (subfolder.path)
Next subfolder
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "File Path"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Folder Name"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "File Name"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "File Extensions"
Dim i, o As Integer
'i = 1
'o = 1
Dim one, two As Long
one = Len(path) - 1
two = Len(Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\") - 1))
'two = Len(Left(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - 1))
ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1) = Right(path, one - two)
For Each file In folder.Files
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = path
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Left(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Mid(file.Name, InStrRev(file.Name, ".") + 1)

Next file

    Set file = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set subfolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Be aware that `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` relies on every file having an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you got the error because one of the file names didn't contain a dot. In that case `InstrRev` returns 0 and the 2nd parameter of your `Left`-statement will get `-1` which is invalid in VBA.

Split such complex command into pieces - it helps you to identify errors.

```
Dim lastcell As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set lastcell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With

Dim p As Long
p = InStrRev(file.name, ".")
If p > 0 Then
    lastcell.Value = Left(file.name, p - 1)
    lastcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(file.name, p + 1)
Else
    lastcell.Value = file.name
    lastcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, quick answer. If you come any time to Spain, you know that I will buy you some drinks.

Answer (score 0):

A FileSytemObject has methods [GetBaseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getbasename-method) and [GetExtensionName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getextensionname-method)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Principal()

    Range("A1:D1") = Array("File Path", "Folder Name", "File Name", "File Extensions")
    Call GetFiles("C:\Users\DGGC\Desktop\UNIR BOGC\")
  
End Sub

Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)
 
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object, file As Object
    Dim lastRow As Long
       
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(lastRow + 1, "B") = folder.Name
    For Each file In folder.Files
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
        Cells(lastRow, "A") = path
        Cells(lastRow, "C") = fso.getBaseName(file.Name)
        Cells(lastRow, "D") = fso.getExtensionName(file.Name)
    Next file

    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
        GetFiles (subfolder.path)
    Next subfolder
   
End Sub
```